# SQL Display Distinct records and include a field if certain data is found

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What I'm trying to accomplish is display distinct data but also display a field on each row if a particular row has a certain data.

The thing thats confusing me is the fact that I still need it to be distinct and if I attempt to do another join i get more rows..

I just wish to keep the same results i'm retrieving but with an additional column that tells me - This equipment (row) needs repairs because at least one of its properties stated so... Hope this makes sense, not sure if I'm explaining myself clearly here.

**The Main Table (Inspection Table)**
[image]

In the above table, Notice `FK_Sequence` Each entry has around 17 which the user is required to answer OK or REPAIR (this is the `FK_Status`)

My current Query is the following and results just an Employee and the equipment they worked on.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
            a.EnteredDate,
            bb.EmployeeId,
            bb.EmployeeName,
            dd.EquipmentId,
            dd.EquipmentName

            FROM dbo.PIT_Inspection a

            INNER JOIN dbo.EmployeeName bb
            ON a.FK_EmployeeName = bb.PK_EmployeeName

            INNER JOIN dbo.EquipmentName dd
            ON a.FK_EquipmentName = dd.PK_EquipmentName
```

Results for above query:

[image]

But then here is where my question comes in. Notice the Main Table - `FK_Status` of `2` on Line 19.. I would like to detect this and for this particular Employee Display Repair in an additional column in the table above named `StatusName`.

Comment: Use a correlated sub-query in the select list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT`, then you can use a conditional count to see how many rows have a status of 2, if it is more than none then display `REPAIR`

```
SELECT  a.EnteredDate,
        bb.EmployeeId,
        bb.EmployeeName,
        dd.EquipmentId,
        dd.EquipmentName,
        StatusName = CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN a.FK_Status = 2 THEN 1 END) > 0 
                            THEN 'REPAIR' 
                            ELSE '' 
                        END
FROM dbo.PIT_Inspection a

INNER JOIN dbo.EmployeeName bb
ON a.FK_EmployeeName = bb.PK_EmployeeName

INNER JOIN dbo.EquipmentName dd
ON a.FK_EquipmentName = dd.PK_EquipmentName

GROUP BY a.EnteredDate, bb.EmployeeId, bb.EmployeeName, dd.EquipmentId, dd.EquipmentName;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  a.EnteredDate,
  bb.EmployeeId,
  bb.EmployeeName,
  dd.EquipmentId,
  dd.EquipmentName,
  CASE WHEN SUM(CASE FK_Status WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 
       THEN 'Repair' ELSE 'OK' END AS StatusName
FROM dbo.PIT_Inspection a
  INNER JOIN dbo.EmployeeName bb
    ON a.FK_EmployeeName = bb.PK_EmployeeName
  INNER JOIN dbo.EquipmentName dd
    ON a.FK_EquipmentName = dd.PK_EquipmentName
GROUP BY
  a.EnteredDate,
  bb.EmployeeId,
  bb.EmployeeName,
  dd.EquipmentId,
  dd.EquipmentName
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the query with the distinct as a sub query, then join to get the "additional information". Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT (your orig fields, but take from inspection where you took from a)
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT a.FK_EmployeeName, a.EnteredDate, FK_EquipmentName
    FROM dbo.PIT_Inspection a) inspection
INNER JOIN dbo.EmployeeName bb
        ON inspection.FK_EmployeeName = bb.PK_EmployeeName

        INNER JOIN dbo.EquipmentName dd
        ON inspection.FK_EquipmentName = dd.PK_EquipmentName
```